# Does Synthetic Meat patent improve food production in all subsequent weeks of the campaign mode missions?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

The Synthetic Meat patent's description says "Greenhouse Farm is permanently boosted" but what does it mean exactly? Does it increase the production by 1 level and last for the entire duration of the remaining weeks in the mission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthetic Meat is a patent available on Io that makes farms act as if they are affected by an Adrenaline Boost. This means they will produce twice as much food and use twice as much water and power. This does not stack with other Adrenaline Boosts from the black market.

In the campaign, it behaves like any other patent, lasting until the end of the campaign if bought, or for multiple weeks if awarded for a mission.

Comment: Does it last through subsequent weeks?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Yes, like any free patent in the campaign.

Comment: thanks, but you should add that comment into the answer coz that's really the *meat* of my question